# Sidebar with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a CSS sidebar. It should be hidden by default, with just this image coming out (see below) from the right. As soon as the user hover over this image, it should come out and reveal a little box with some text in it.

The sidebar should not be to the top-right corner but at half of the screen height. I can already do this on the left and without animation (see code). It looks impossible to me: I hate CSS (!!!) and I hope someone could help me to do this. Thanks a lot in advance for your patience and forgive me for the question but I'm a big noob on CSS.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/WSZbe/1/ this is my attempt so far...

```
#side{
position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:40px;
allign: center;
background-color: blue;
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you can't really do this with CSS alone. In order to have the top placed 50% from the top of the window, you need to use javascript to get the window's height. Also, the image looks like it's supposed to be on the left, not the right.

Comment: I dont fully understand what you need... you want the image to stay on side and display that div when you hover over image? With your actual solution you are shifting the div that contains your image, which is not what you want at all I guess :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#side{
position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:40px;
allign: center;
background-color: blue; 
}
#side:hover{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:200px;
  height:40px;
  allign: center;
  background-color: blue; 
}
```

Comment: doesn't work at all. It just get stuck on the top-left corner and, at hover, the image start to tremble back and forth. See the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/WSZbe/1/

Comment: Okay here's the deal - you need more than just a div on a page, that div needs a container to position it, then you need to also understand the animation via pure css wont be pretty. http://jsfiddle.net/vrxFH/ this. Using jQuery you can do this and it will work much better.

Comment: Yes, maybe learn a little about html/css/javascript before developing pages, or doing something completely different if you "hate CSS" :-D

Comment: in fact I managed to render this using the html5 canvas and now works fine ;)

Comment: this is confusing... you have a hard time with basic css but then do it in canvas... Why didn't you just JS the whole time then?

Comment: that's confusing also to me. I do advanced programming with JS+canvas but almost get lost with CSS. I just have very poor documentation and books on CSS asked for help here. Thanks anyway for your answers, I've learned new stuff by trying them! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I have no time to tune it right now, but you should get the idea if thats what you wanted... [FIDDLE Link](http://jsfiddle.net/WSZbe/4/)